# Atom package: create a file

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I'm making a package based on the on-save package. When a file of a certain extension is saved I want it to take the text of that file, do some stuff to it, and save it with a different extension. But I'm having trouble trying to work out how to create a new file. Is there an existing Atom function I can use for this? I've been trying to use `import {exec} from 'child_process'` and `exec('echo ' + text + '>' + path)` But I've found that that doesn't really work with line breaks. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to save the file, you can use [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback):

**Example:**

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs';

const data = 'Hello World';

writeFile('message.txt', data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

If you want to create this file within Atom, you would do something this:

```
atom.workspace.open('message.txt')
.then( newTab => {
  newTab.insertText('Hello World');
  newTab.save();
});
```

See the [Atom API documentation](https://atom.io/docs/api/latest/AtomEnvironment) for details.